# ORDER BY ignored as there is a user-defined clustered index in the table

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `tableMain` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `value1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   'value2' varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   'value3' int NOT NULL,
   'value4' timestamp NOT NULL,
   'value5' int NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

So I create that table and I want it to be always ordered by value2, if there is two a like it should sort by value3 and after that value4.

So I try to do it by that

```
ALTER TABLE tableMain
ORDER BY value2 ASC, value3 ASC, value4 ASC
```

And when I run that code I get an error:

> Error Code: 1105. ORDER BY ignored as there is a user-defined clustered   index in the table 'tableMain'

I want to add that I got that as a homework for school and others who have same task can run this ALTER TABLE line. So I'm little bit confused and don't know what to do.

Comment: You already have a primary index on id, do the order by in your queries

Comment: But why then others can run it? And what do you mean by queries?

Comment: @RVstack: do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableMain`. That will show that your table is using InnoDB storage engine. An `ORDER BY` table attribute doesn't make sense with InnoDB, because InnoDB tables are *always* ordered by the cluster index of the table. By "queries", dbinns66 is referring to the `SELECT` statements that you run to retrieve rows from the tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we want rows returned in a particular sequence, we can specify a suitable `ORDER BY` clause in the query.

The idea that rows need to be "ordered" in a table flies in the face of relational database theory.  (A relation is a set of tuples; altering the "order" of tuples within a relation does not alter the relation.)

Translating the theory into practice, with the InnoDB storage engine, it doesn't make sense to specify `ORDER BY` as a table attribute, since an InnoDB table will always be ordered (rows stored in sequence), arranged by its cluster index.

In the case of the MyISAM storage engine, specifying `ORDER BY` may improve performance of some queries. The `ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY` statement only reorganizes the table one time. The "order" of the rows may not be preserved when subsequent `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements are run.

To reiterate: if we need rows returned in a particular order, we should not depend on the "order" that rows are physically stored in a table. It's imperative that we include an `ORDER BY` on the query.

To really improve performance with large tables, adding appropriate indexes is the way to go.

---

As to why your classmates get the statement to run, and your statement returns an error... the most likely explanation is that their tables are using the **MyISAM** storage engine, while your table is using the **InnoDB** storage engine.

(Whatever the assignment is, changing the storage engine of your table can not be the right answer... MyISAM storage engine is an appropriate choice for some use cases; but InnoDB is the most appropriate choice for traditional "relational database" uses cases.)

---

If your requirement is that your InnoDB table to "always be ordered by" a set of columns (for whatever reason), then have the cluster index include those columns as the leading columns.  You can do that by declaring those columns as the leading columns of the PRIMARY KEY of your table. You can create a UNIQUE INDEX on the `id` column.

```
CREATE TABLE `tableMain` 
( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, `value1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
, `value2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
, `value3` INT NOT NULL
, `value4` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
, `value5` INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (`value2`,`value3`,`value4`,`id`)
, UNIQUE KEY `tableMain_UX1` (`id`)
)
```

In reality, we'd never do this... because any secondary indexes are going to include the PRIMARY KEY values as the "pointer" back to the cluster index, and that's going to be an incredible waste of resources. In practice, we'd leave `id` as the PRIMARY KEY of the table, and create a secondary index on the other columns...

```
CREATE TABLE `tableMain` 
( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, `value1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
, `value2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
, `value3` INT NOT NULL
, `value4` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
, `value5` INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
, KEY `tableMain_IX1` (`value2`,`value3`,`value4`)
)
```